# Office 2011 on Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook

I recently installed Microsoft Office 2011 and that automatically took care of the upgrade from Entourage 2008 to Outlook 2011.

I need to reinstall SnowLeopard and am trying to find the pst where all my mails are stored.

Does anyone have a clue as to where the mails are stored?

The reason is that once the mails are transferred from the server to the client application, the server is configured to delete the mail and I don't have a backup.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Outlook, but the rest of the Office user information is stored in `~/Documents/Microsoft User Data/`. Check out `Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity/` if it's in there.

Comment: @Panther24: for posterity, if you found it, could give the full path, so I can include it in my post?

Comment: the actual path is <user>/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Office 2011 Identities/Main Identity

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where the mails are stored as I don't use Office, but here's how I would find out:

1. Download and install [fseventer](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:fseventer:start), which has the ability to record filesystem changes,
2. Open Outlook,
3. Start recording with fseventer,
4. Receive a mail, and see what happens.

Hope that was usefull.